# Shopware 6 SEO URL in different languages

Tags: shopware, shopware6

With the...

```
seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: 'some-product-id' })
```

...function, it is possible to create the SEO URL within a twig template.

Is there also an option to create the URL in different languages? I imagined something like this:

```
seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: 'some-product-id', languageId: 'some-language-id' })
```

Expected result:

- de-DE: http://localhost/hauptprodukt
- en-GB: http://localhost/en/main-product

If not, how could I achieve this?

Comment: With `seoUrl()` it's not possible, as the second parameter is just for adding URL parameters. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787887/how-to-get-current-product-or-category-url-equivalent-for-all-other-channels-in) maybe that's helpful. Not a full implementation though.